# Does this wave function violate any rules of Quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, identical-particles

I am studying bosons and fermions in quantum mechanics. We learned that for a two-particle system with identical bosons, the wave function can have the form (assume symmetric spin)
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt2} (\psi_{1} (x_{a}) \psi_{2} (x_{b}) + \psi_{1} (x_{b}) \psi_{2} (x_{a}))$$

where $\psi_{1}, \psi_{2}$ denote two single-particle states and $x_{a}, x_{b}$ denote the two bosons. Will the following also be a possible wave function (assume symmetric spin)?
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt2} (\psi_{1} (x_{a}) \psi_{1} (x_{b}) + \psi_{2} (x_{a}) \psi_{2} (x_{b})) $$
This wave function is still symmetric under the exchange of the two bosons. However, each individual product wave function implies that the two bosons are at the same energy state.
**Does this second wave function violate any rule, or can it describe the wave function of the system of two bosons?**

Comment: you have to edit the second line of formulas , there is a psi as a variable at the last and an extra parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that the second wavefunction is symmetric under particle exchange. But the wavefunctions won't solve the two-particle Schrodinger equation with the correct eigenvalues.

Comment: Could the wave function be thought of as the superposition of two two-particle states, each with equal probability? Or can it just not describe a system of two identical bosons at all?

Comment: It is indeed a superposition of two product states. What should be intuitive, however, is that whatever the composite state is, it should have energy eigenvalues as a sum of those of the individual eigenstates. For example, for an exciton, the wavefunction is written just as a product of individual electron and hole(both fermions) states. See for example https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/529d/fcd98ce24b70e7539582eb1b1c96c6457f44.pdf?_ga=2.101282113.1353895216.1611377875-1167585833.1611377875

Comment: Going off the comment by @ZeroTheHero, can this wave function still describe the system of two bosons even though it's not a solution to the time-independent SE? I was thinking in analogous to a single particle wave function for the infinite square well, say $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(|E_{1}\rangle+|E_{2}\rangle+|E_{3}\rangle)$, which describes a particle with equal probability of being in any of the three states.